# Find files based on a date in the filename

Tags: php, datetime

I have 100 text files in a directory.

The format of the filename is  `abcd_2011_04_20.txt`

I need to read only TODAY's file and the past 7 days files . How do I go about it?
EDIT 1 :

I already have a function dirTxt(dirname) which returns the name of the files as an array . How do I identify the current date's corresponding file?? and then get the previous 7 day's files??

EDIT 2 :

THE array returns the following

'graph.txt' 
  'graph1.txt' 
'abcd_2011-04-12.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-13.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-24.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-15.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-16.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-17.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-18.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-19.txt' 
  'abcd_2011-04-20.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example

```
$dt = time();   // today... or use $dt = strtotime('2010-04-20'); to set custom start date.
$past_days = 7; // number of past days
$filesindir = dirTxt('your_dir');

for ($i=0; $i<=$past_days; $i++) {
  $filename = 'abcd_' . date('Y_m_d', $dt) . '.txt';
  $files[] = $filename;
  $dt = strtotime('-1 day', $dt);
  } 

$files = array_intersect($filesindir, $files);

print_r($files);
```

### Output (might be like this, depends of $filesindir array)

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcd_2011_04_21.txt
    [1] => abcd_2011_04_20.txt
    [2] => abcd_2011_04_18.txt
    [3] => abcd_2011_04_15.txt
)
```

Comment: Hi , But the problem is I have a function called dirTxt() which returns the name of every single text file in that directory ... How do I identify the current day's file and then get the past 7 days files ??? please help

Comment: @Zac, can you post in your question, part of that list? Does every file has "abcd_" prefix (or generally same prefix)?

Comment: But I have a function dirTxt(dirname) which returns the name of the files as an array . How do I identify the current date's corresponding file?? and then get the previous 7 day's files??

Comment: @Zac, look at my answer's output? Do you have that filename-format in your file-array? There are filenames for today and 7 days back. Can you just use it?

Comment: I don't get you... I added this to your code.... but it won't work .. `$text11  is the individual filename `   >   $filename = 'abcd_' . date('Y_m_d', $dt) . '.txt';  
  if ( $filename == $text11)  
  {  
  echo "$filename <br />"; // do something with $filename  
  // ... more code ...
  $dt = strtotime('-1 day', $dt);  
  
  }

Comment: ur format is correct, but the array will have hundreds of such files... so I am using $filename == $text11  to identify the file for current date... for some reason it wouldn't work .. shd I use strcmp  ??

Comment: @Zac, once again. Post result of your dirTxt() function (not complete if it's too large). Every answer here is correct according to your question. Obviously, you missed something to tell us. Edit your question, don't post code samples in comments. Just post that array because I can't guess what's in it.

Comment: @Zac, if you already know that filename e.g. `abcd_2011_04_19.txt` exists? Why you search for it in array? Just use it, and if question is how to get that filename, see $filename variable in my answer. That's all.

Comment: okay, the array returns, abcd_2011_04_12.txt  ..... until abcd_2011_04_20.txt   in 1 array .... SO, I need to have abcd_2011_04_20.txt ....until abcd_2011_04_13.txt  in the $files array ... how do I achieve this ... THanks a lot ..

Comment: I DO NOT know that the file exists ... if one file does not exist, it must not return the corresponding file ... that's another prob/

Comment: @Zac, wait a sek... now, that's clear what you want. give me minute.

Comment: @Zac, OK, now it works. Pass your array of files in `$filesindir` variable and `$files` array will return only existing filenames from your array. Look again my code.

Comment: I used strcmp of the files of my original array and $files of your array to find the matches and display the match ! works like a charm ... thanks a lot man ,, u r great !

Comment: @Zac, yes [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) returns elements from first array (list of your files in directory) that exist in another array (list of files by date we created). In short, computes the intersection of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I made a *helper* function, in case you need to use it again somewhere. If not, you could easily place its code inside of the loop's body.

```
function getFileName($unixTime) {
    return 'abcd_' . date('Y_m_j', $unixTime) . '.txt';
} 

$files = array();
foreach(range(0, 6) as $dayOffset) {
   $files[] = getFileName(strtotime('-' . $dayOffset . ' day'));
}

var_dump($files)
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/u9ZRdBDZ).

#### Output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_21.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_20.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_19.txt"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_18.txt"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_17.txt"
  [5]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_16.txt"
  [6]=>
  string(19) "abcd_2011_04_15.txt"
```

#### Update

As for reading them, just loop...

```
foreach($files as $file) {
   if ( ! is_file($file)) {
       continue;
   }
   $contents = file_get_contents($file);
}
```

Comment: But I have a function dirTxt(dirname) which returns the name of the files as an array . How do I identify the current date's corresponding file?? and then get the previous 7 day's files??....

Comment: @Zac You can use my helper function for the current file... `getFileName(time())`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date out of the filename and compare it to today's date.

PHP has [string manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and [date/time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for this.

---

```
<?php
function isWithinLastSevenDays($str) {
   $pos = strpos($str, "_");
   if ($pos === FALSE)
      throw new Exception("Invalid filename format");

   $str = str_replace('_', '-', substr($str, $pos+1, strlen($str)-$pos-1-4));
   $d1 = new DateTime($str);
   $d2 = new DateTime();
   $d2->modify('-7 days'); // sub() only since PHP 5.3

   return ($d2 < $d1);
}

$str = "abcd_2011_04_20.txt";
var_dump(isWithinLastSevenDays($str));

$str = "abcd_2011_04_10.txt";
var_dump(isWithinLastSevenDays($str));

/*
Output:

bool(true)
bool(false)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'abcd_' . date('Y_m_d') . '.txt';
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    die("File $filename does not exist");
}

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
```

Use `date('Y_m_d', strtotime('-2 days'))` to get other dates.